# Why is my Internet Explorer group policy ignored?

Tags: security, group-policy, windows-server-2016, windows-10, internet-explorer

In light of the [recently discovered MSHTML vulnerability](https://msrc.microsoft.com/update-guide/vulnerability/CVE-2021-40444) (and because it's a good idea in general), I want to disallow downloading of ActiveX components via group policy. However, it appears that my policy settings are ignored.

Here's my group policy setting:

[image: Group Policy Settings]

Then I refresh the group policy on my client PC (in a non-elevated shell, since this is a user policy):

```
C:\Users\{redacted}>gpupdate /force
Updating policy...

Computer Policy update has completed successfully.
User Policy update has completed successfully.
```

Yet IE seems to ignore my new settings:

[image: IE settings]

I'm sure I'm overlooking something obvious. What is it?

Comment: What is the Security Filtering of the GPO set to?

Comment: @joeqwerty: It's kept at the default value, "Authenticated Users".

Comment: Can you generate a `gpresult` report and take a look at it, see if you can see your policy?

Comment: I believe for IE10+, it may be preferrable/more modern to use Preferences > Control Panel Settings > Internet Settings > right-click > New > Internet Explorer 10.

Comment: @Swisstone: Thanks, the output of `gpresult /Z` helped me find the root cause. I'll write a self-answer with the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **disabled** the policy setting. This means that the group policy setting is not applied.

What you need to do instead is to **enable** the policy setting and then **configure** the policy setting to **disabled**. In other words, instead of this:

[image: wrong]

you should do that:

[image: correct]

You can also see the difference in the summary view. This is wrong:

[image: wrong-summary]

And this is correct:

[image: correct-summary]

---

Unfortunately, the name of the setting (which needs to be enabled) and the name of the option inside the setting (which needs to be disabled) are exactly the same, which makes such an error easy to overlook. As @Swisstone mentioned in the comments, `gpresult` can help here. This is the output of `gpresult /Z` (`/Z` for super-verbose) in the "wrong" case:

```
GPO: Internet Explorer
    Folder Id: Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\3\1001
    State:       disabled
```

And this in the correct case:

```
GPO: Internet Explorer
    Folder Id: Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\3\1001
    Value:       3, 0, 0, 0
    State:       Enabled
```

The latter entry sets this registry value to `dword:00000003`, which is your intended result. Note that IE respects this setting now:

[image: IE]